# html php mysql secure

Tags: php, html, mysql, security

I use php to manage html and now I have problem with input date in mysql.
All with my input in MySQL or update or delete in MySQL is ok but how I can make security for input data in mysql because if some one open to see my html source code with browser he can see my predefined inputs and he can change thats in html and after that enter wronk inputs in mysql.

This is my code:

```
    Options Value: <select name="extend">
            <option value="<?php $_end1;$newDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_end. " + 1 month"));echo $newDate;?>">1 Month</option>
```

Now when if someone open browser and see my code he can replease 1 month with several month and that in MySQL.

How can I this secure and or hide that in HTML.

Thx

Comment: you cannot hide what's in your html, at the better, you can obfuscate, but that just makes it a bit harder to read, not impossible. What you have to do is either verify all values on server side (php) if values are simple of predefined. If more complex, you can add hashes to your form in its building in php to ensure data validity (the hash needs to change, based on timestamp for example)

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to have fields or input that can't be edited by the user, such as the current date that the form was submitted on or something along the lines of that, you need to do do all of that on the server side (not the client side). Any data that is submitted from the client side can (and you should treat it like it will) be changed.

Instead of having form fields with preset values, fields that are hidden, fields that are disabled, data that is rendered with JavaScript, or any other way you could think of storing data on the client side, do those things on the server side. You can use a PHP script to do this, seeing as you're already making use of PHP. When you submit the form it has to go to some sort of a server side script, do that logic there and submit that logic to a database.

Answer (score 0):

filter all your received user input. This might be clear for free text inputs, but should be done as well for predefined  values.

Easiest for extending might be to only accept a certain number. For example 1, 2 or 3.

`$extend = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'extend', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);` is the first step, but you should also check if $extend is not equal to an illegal number.
`if(in_array($extend, range(1,3)){ }`

input like numbers is a lot more simple to check than a range of dates.

But even when that would be needed: it is possible to make your own validation function.

It is not possible to limit the browser or the user to only send certain data in a form. Either they could use a tool in the browser to change the habits of a form element, or they could rebuild the form completely in their own htmlpage or other tool

Answer (score 0):

There is very simple answer to your question - you can **NOT** secure html and you should not even try. Every browser is equipped with developer tools and even without browser anyone can send to your server whatever they want. This is how Internet works.

What you **SHOULD** do is to verify your input data on server side where user has no access. In your case you should have array of allowed inputs or function assessing if input from user is valid.

More, if you know what will be the algorithm eg. (`$_end` + 1month) than you do not need to get from user result but only value of `$_end`. You can calculate `$newDate` just before inserting data to database - this way user will have no way of changing it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please be carefull with your writing, it is pretty hard to understand your problem.

Secondly, if you want to "hide" PHP code to the user, you could write your code in a different way :

1. You create a form in which users will be able to fill some informations, and for example a date, like in your example. If this date is an option, it can have some value, as the one you show.
2. Then when the user submit the file, you make a checking on the variables. If you want this form to show a price, to add some data to a database, or whatever, you do some checking to be sure that the values are correct. For example, if you want to calculate a price, you will check the date the user selected, and calculate the price from this date. With this method, even if user changed the code, they will not be able to change the checking (at least not easily).
3. And to conclude you show a page asking the user for confirmation. This way, he will check if the informations are correct, and you can ask to re-fill some fields if you detected some invalids values

That's hard to show some concrete code, since I don't really know what you want to do, but I hope this explanation was clear. Don't hesitate to ask some questions, I'll try to answer.

Answer (score 0):

darling brother:
you have 3 method:
1: define a variables instead of 1 month
2: use encryption method for php enciding that provide encryption php cides to unformatted charachters (ionCube  )
3: usin my sql encryption : MD5

Comment: it seems that MD5 is no longer secure, for example https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/52461/how-weak-is-md5-as-a-password-hashing-function among other links